# JavaScript Recursion Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a plugin for JS text effects. The plugin is supposed to take a target, generate a random string of the length of target, and then eventually convert the randomly generated string to the target, one char at a time.

The following is the code which I believe is facing the issues.

```
$.fn.scramble2 = function(){
$x=0;
var $target = "Welcome To California";
appear($("#text").text().trim(), $target, "", "");
var $timer = setInterval(function(){
    if($flag==0){
        rearrange($target, 0);
        clearInterval($timer);
    }
}, 1000) ;
}
```

The function `appear` is supposed to generate the random string, char by char. Although I am setting the flag to 0 when appear returns, I believe the recursive statements still run in the background, which is by the rearrange function rearranges all the letters, except the first few.

I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEMJ3/2/) with all the remaining codes. I, probably, am implementing recursion in the wrong manner, and I apologize for that before-hand since recursion is something I have trouble with always.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no recursion in your code. What's with all those `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Comment: There are recursive statements in `appear` and `rearrange` functions. The timeout and intervals are supposed to call the respective functions until the desired condition has been achieved. @zeroflagL

Comment: Recursion means that a function calls itself. `appear` doesn't call itself. I know what `setTimeout` is supposed to do, but I don't know why you use it :)